# How can I specify the color of the line='s' or line=45 line drawn in a qq plot using statsmodels

Tags: python, colors, statsmodels

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.qqplot(residuals, line ='s',dist='norm',color='g',fmt='.g')
plt.grid()
```

[image: qqplot]

I am unable to change the color of the "red line" to a color of my choice by using arguments like `linecolor` and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any answer which could change the color from `sm.qqplot` directly. So I tried by storing the plot in a subplot and then changing the color of the line from there.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(7,4.5))

sm.qqplot(data, line ='45',dist='norm',color='g',fmt='.g', ax=ax)
ax.grid()
ax.set_title('data_qq',fontsize=15)
ax.xaxis.get_label().set_fontsize(12)
ax.yaxis.get_label().set_fontsize(12)
ax.get_lines()[1].set_color("black")
ax.get_lines()[1].set_linewidth("2")
```

[image: Expected plot with linecolor changed]

- I am still interested to know if there is a way to do this from within `sm.qqplot` command.